# how to send a string to listView in another activity ? in android

Tags: android

**Good evening guys,
I'm making an app and I want to know how to send a string to "List-View" in another activity ?**

Comment: I suggest you break this up in two parts: "how to send data to another activity?" and "how to put a string in a listView?". Search these questions on the web (preferably stackoverflow) and go make code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data using the following code -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,newActivity);
intent.putExtra(name, value)
```

name = The name of the extra data
value = The String data value.

```
startActivity(intent);
```

In the new activity, you receive string via following (in onCreate)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String str = intent.getString(name)
```

name = The name of the extra data

Now search the web on how to add a string to list view. You will find it easily